# How to configure https in spring boot 2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have generated a self signed certificate using `keytool`. I have added to my resource folder.
Inside my `application.properties`, I have added

```
security.require-ssl=true

# The format used for the keystore 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

My config file:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new EmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}
```

But I can't still access my application with https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` in `Spring boot 2` instead use `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`.

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}
```

Comment: where is getHttpConnector() method?  also are there any more docs on how to implement https in spring boot 2?